# Как программно передать серверу информацию о скроле странички?

Tags: android, html, сервер, jsoup

Хотелось бы это сделать по средствам Jsoup библиотеки в Android проекте.

Мне это необходимо, т.к. не весь контент выводится в начальной **HTML** страничке и у меня нету к нему доступа, а при скроле страницы вниз постепенно подгружаются и другие элементы, каким образом можно задать такой скрол программе или как можно программно отправить запрос на подгрузку?

Comment: У вас нет доступа, но вы же как-то подгружаете потом даные?! Или вы в адаптере подгружаете для каждого отдельного элемента?

Comment: Уточните, вопрос про RecyclerView, ListView или WebView

Comment: Ясно, понял, что вопрос не понят, я имел ввиду HTML страницу и её скроллинг в браузере, только я подключаюсь к html страничке средствами библиотеки Jsoup. Я выполняю конект к странице функцией connect(ULR)

Comment: Скиньте ту ссылку, которую мы парсили) Просто на словах никто не поймет. я кстати тоже чутка растерялся, когда увидел что 20 картинок только подгрузило

Comment: Собсно сама страница: https://twitter.com/hashtag/rae2015?f=images